# How to integrate a wysiwyg editor to into a jQuery template?

Tags: javascript, jquery-templates

I'm making heavy use of jQuery Templates to create a JSON-driven client-side content admin system. Creating forms and populating them with data via javascript templating is a breeze, but I would like to add a WYSIWYG editor to edit text in place of a simple textarea.

Does anyone have a way to do this, or know of a specific WYSIWYG editor that will play nice with jQuery templates?

Answer (score 0):

I think FCKEditor has both a jQuery binding and uses textareas. You can do something like this:

```
$.tmpl('myTemplate', data)
     .appendTo( '#holder' )
     .find('#editorTextarea')
     .fckEditor();
```

Comment: I believe the latest version, CKEditor, has built-in jQuery support. FCKeditor (the previous version) does not, though of course it's not incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE also has jQuery compatible version here: http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php